# How do i uniquely identify a row in a csv by a column value, and then later check another column for a "Passed" keyword and print it

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv, parsing

I have a CSV File,

```
APIName_UniqueId,TC_Status,Comment
123456,PASSED,API "123456_Get Download Credential_1" is PASSED 
123457,PASSED,API "123457_Get Upload Credential_1" is PASSED
```

I want to check the APIName_UniqueId and check for the Comment if there is a "Passed" Keyword.

if both the conditions qualify i want to print the Comment, else print a failed statment.

I tried with this script but it won't work,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Work\Test\Python_Scripts\Final_Result.csv')

for value_i in df.APIName_UniqueId:

if df[(df['APIName_UniqueId'] == 123456) &(df['Comment'].str.contains('PASSED'))]:
             print(df['Comment'])

    else:
        print('Test Case Failed')
```

Can someone Help me out  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.where` passing 3 arguments: (1) condition, (2) result if True and (3) result if False.

```
(np.where((df['APIName_UniqueId'] == 123456) & 
          (df['Comment'].str.contains('PASSED')), df['Comment'], 'Test Case Failed')
)
output:
array(['API "123456_Get Download Credential_1" is PASSED ',
       'Test Case Failed'], dtype=object)
```

Just remembering that it is recommended whenever possible avoid using for loop structures, they are not optimized like the native `pandas` and `numpy` functions

Answer (score 0):

This should help. I usually write in python3, so the syntax could be off a little.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Work\Test\Python_Scripts\Final_Result.csv')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['APIName_UniqueId'] == 123456) and row['Comment'].str.contains('PASSED'))]:
        print(row['Comment'])

    else:
        print('Test Case Failed')
```